# Javascript validation for specific number

Tags: javascript

My current attempt at trying to stop spam bots from submitting my form is asking users to enter two out of four specific numbers from an image. I need help asking javascript to check the textfield for those two specific numbers (onblur) and not allow any other two characters to pass which is what's currently happening.  I'm using spry as well to validate the field.  Also, are spam bots programmed to turn javascript off?  If so, this is a waste of time.

```
function validateSecurity()
 {
 var x=document.forms["form"]["security"].value;
 if (x != 89)
   {
   alert("Incorrect");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't be just better to use [proven tools](http://recaptcha.net) for that ? Making wheel of this kind is not funny anymore :)

Comment: doesn't appear you've thought this through very far....what if javascript is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the proper way to do it, now in modern age where we have jQuery, Angular and other frameworks, your function is most probably being called out of scope.
Set it on the window object, like this:

```
window.validateSecurity = function(){ ... }
```

and it will probably work just fine.
Here is a jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/B9pzW/

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, Yair Tavor - I will give this a shot and see if it works. I'm working with an older website and just trying to get by long enough while testing the new site before publishing.